# multipart/form-data support in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript

How can I submit multipart/formdata in ClojureScript? Is there any library that supports this? I can fallback to e.g. `jquery.form.js` but would prefer a plain ClojureScript solution.

Comment: you'll need some iframe hack for uploads, start here http://www.closurecheatsheet.com/net#goog-net-iframeio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [cljs-http](https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http):

```
;; Form parameters in a POST request (simple)
(http/post "http://example.com" {:form-params {:key1 "value1" :key2 "value2"}})

;; Form parameters in a POST request (array of values)
(http/post "http://example.com" {:form-params {:key1 [1 2 3] :key2 "value2"}})
```

**====== UPDATE =======**

You'll need some iframe hack. Read [this](http://ggenikus.github.io/blog/2013/11/04/clojurescript-ajax-file-uploading/) and [this](http://www.closurecheatsheet.com/net#goog-net-iframeio):

```
;; Imports
(:require [goog.events :as gev])
(:import [goog.net IframeIo]
         [goog.net EventType]

(defn upload []
  (let [io (IframeIo.)]
    (gev/listen io
                (aget goog.net.EventType "SUCCESS")
                #(js/alert "SUCCESS!"))
    (gev/listen io
                (aget goog.net.EventType "ERROR")
                #(js/alert "ERROR!"))
    (gev/listen io
                (aget goog.net.EventType "COMPLETE")
                #(js/alert "COMPLETE!"))
    (.setErrorChecker io #(not= "ok" (.getResponseText io)))
    (.sendFromForm io (dom/by-id "form") "/upload")))
```

Comment: AFAIK it does not support multipart/formdata

Answer (score 4):

I recently made a pull request to cljs-http to support form-data. Util r0man merges it, you can see instruction in my version's README at https://github.com/myguidingstar/cljs-http

Edited: The pull request has been merged. See the original repository instead.

This is how I did it:

```
(defn generate-form-data [params]
  (let [form-data (js/FormData.)]
    (doseq [[k v] params]
      (.append form-data (name k) v))
    form-data))

(defn upload [file]
  (go (let [response (<! (http/post "http://localhost/upload"
                                    {:body (generate-form-data {:file file})}))]
        (prn (:status response))
        (prn (:body response)))))

;; some-dom-element is a single file upload input
;; <input type="file">
(upload (-> some-dom-element .-files first))
```

If you don't want to use cljs-http, see `cljs-http.core/request` in its source code for how to make a direct call to `XhrIo`
https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http/blob/master/src/cljs_http/core.cljs

Comment: Simple and elegant solution using `js/FormData`. However, that won't work for ie 9 and below or?

Comment: I'm afraid most of Clojurescript libraries can't compared to JQuery in wide range of compatibility :(

Comment: If you take this serious, try finding some pure javascript implementation of FormData. Maybe this one, though I haven't looked through its source code https://github.com/felixge/node-form-data